# Align array of structures to make table

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, data-structures, struct, alignment

I need to create a table using a array of structures, but I have a problem for which I did not find a solution other than using gotoxy from the windows.h library .
Here is the code that I made but text and numbers in columns are not aligned with the fields in the first row :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct  student
  {
    int broj_indeksa ;
    int godina_upisa ;
    char ime_studenta [20] ;
    char prezime_studenta [30] ;
    float prosecna_ocena_I ;
    float prosecna_ocena_II ;
    float prosecna_ocena_III ;

 } ISPIT [5000] ;

int main()
    {
    struct student ISPIT[5000] ;
    int n, i, j ;
    printf("Uneti broj studenata :");
    scanf("%d", &n) ;
    printf("\n");

    for( i= 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("Uneti podatke za studenta broj %d\n \n" ,  i+1) ;
        printf("Broj indeksa : \n") ;
        scanf("%d", &ISPIT[ i ].broj_indeksa) ;
        printf("Godina upisa : \n") ;
        scanf("%d" , &ISPIT[ i ].godina_upisa) ;
        printf("Ime : \n") ;
        scanf("%s", &ISPIT[ i ].ime_studenta) ;
        printf("Prezime : \n") ;
        scanf("%s" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prezime_studenta );
        printf("Prosecna ocena u prvoj godini : \n") ;
        scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_I  );
        printf("Prosecna ocena u drugoj godini : \n") ;
        scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_II  );
        printf("Prosecna ocena u trecoj godini : \n") ;
        scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_III  );
        system("cls");
    }
    printf ("Broj indeksa   Godina upisa    Ime    Prezime    Prosek I    Prosek II    Prosek III");   // HOW CAN I ALIGN THIS FOR LOOP BELOW ?
    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    printf("%d  ",ISPIT [ i ].broj_indeksa );
    printf("%d  ",ISPIT [ i ].godina_upisa );
    printf("%s  ",ISPIT [ i ].ime_studenta );
    printf("%s  ",ISPIT [ i ].prezime_studenta );
    printf("%.1f    ",ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I );
    printf("%.1f    ",ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II );
    printf("%.1f    ",ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III );
    printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

My question is : How can I have table looking array of structures without using any libraries except standard ones ?

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.   2) when using the input/format specifier: '%s' or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTER modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer. because those specifiers always append a NUL byte.  using the MAX CHARACTER modifier avoids any possibility of buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior

Comment: in C, referencing the name of an array degrades to the address of the first byte of the array, I.E.  `scanf("%s", &ISPIT[ i ].ime_studenta) ;`  should be: `if( 1 != scanf( "%19s", ISPIT[ i ].ime_studenta ) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed to input the 'ime_studenta' field\n" );  // cleanup then exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use printf with left-justify flag (-).

```
 printf("%-25s%-20s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", "Broj Indeksa", "Godina Upisa", "Ime", "Prezime", "Ocena1", "Ocena2", "Ocena3");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
    printf("%-25d%-20d%-15s%-15s%-15.2f%-15.2f%-15.2f\n", ISPIT [ i ].broj_indeksa,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].godina_upisa,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].ime_studenta,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].prezime_studenta,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II,
                                                          ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III);
 }
```

Comment: on the '%s' output format specifiers, 1) the '%-15s' is not large enough to hold the  field, which (depending on the specific variable) is 20 or 30 bytes.  The current item is only enforcing left justification and the minimum number of bytes.  suggest: '%-20.20s' and '%-30.30s'.   Similar considerations exist for both `printf()` statements

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct  student
{
    int broj_indeksa ;
    int godina_upisa ;
    char ime_studenta [15] ;
    char prezime_studenta [25] ;
    float prosecna_ocena_I ;
    float prosecna_ocena_II;
    float prosecna_ocena_III ;

} ISPIT [5000] , a;

int main()
{
    struct student ISPIT[5000] ;
    int n, i, j;
    //      UCITAVANJE BROJA STUDENATA
    printf("Uneti broj studenata :");
    scanf("%d", &n) ;
    printf("\n");
    //      UCITAVANJE POJEDINACNIH PODATAKA ZA STUDENTA
    for( i= 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            printf("Uneti podatke za studenta broj %d\n \n" ,  i+1) ;
            printf("Broj indeksa : \n") ;
            scanf("%d", &ISPIT[ i ].broj_indeksa) ;
            printf("Godina upisa : \n") ;
            scanf("%d" , &ISPIT[ i ].godina_upisa) ;
            printf("Ime : \n") ;
            scanf("%s", &ISPIT[ i ].ime_studenta) ;
            printf("Prezime : \n") ;
            scanf("%s" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prezime_studenta );
            printf("Prosecna ocena u prvoj godini : \n") ;
            scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_I  );
            printf("Prosecna ocena u drugoj godini : \n") ;
            scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_II  );
            printf("Prosecna ocena u trecoj godini : \n") ;
            scanf("%f" ,  &ISPIT[ i ].prosecna_ocena_III  );
            system("cls");
        }

        //      PRIKAZIVANJE
    float prosecna_ocena_I ;
    float prosecna_ocena_II;
    float prosecna_ocena_III;
    int k ;

    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; } printf("\n");
    printf("| %-15s | %-15s | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15s | %-15s | %-15s |\n", "Broj Indeksa", "Godina Upisa", "Ime", "Prezime", "Ocena I", "Ocena II", "Ocena III");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("| %-15d | %-15d | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15.1f | %-15.1f | %-15.1f |\n",
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].broj_indeksa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].godina_upisa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].ime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prezime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II  = (ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I +ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II ) / 2,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III = (ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I +ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II +ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III ) / 3);

                                                        for( k = 0 ; k< 137; k++) { printf("_"); }
                                                        printf("\n");
        }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    // SORTIRANJE PREMA GODINI UPISA U OPADAJUCEM PORETKU
    for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
        {
            for ( j =0 ; j < n-i ; j++)
                {
                    if ( ISPIT [ j ].godina_upisa < ISPIT [ j+1 ].godina_upisa)
                        {
                            a= ISPIT [ j ] ;
                            ISPIT [ j ] = ISPIT [ j+1 ] ;
                            ISPIT [ j+1 ] = a ;
                        }
                }
        }

    printf("\n\n") ;
    printf("Posle sortiranja po godini upisa u opadajucem poretku \n\n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; } printf("\n");
    printf("| %-15s | %-15s | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15s | %-15s | %-15s |\n", "Broj Indeksa", "Godina Upisa", "Ime", "Prezime", "Ocena I", "Ocena II", "Ocena III");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("| %-15d | %-15d | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15.1f | %-15.1f | %-15.1f |\n",
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].broj_indeksa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].godina_upisa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].ime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prezime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II ,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III );

                                                        for( k = 0 ; k< 137; k++) { printf("_"); }
                                                        printf("\n");
        }
    for ( i = 1 ; i < n ; i++)
            {
                for ( j = 0 ; j < n-i ; j++)
                    {
                        if ( ISPIT [ j ].prosecna_ocena_III < ISPIT [ j+1 ].prosecna_ocena_III && ISPIT [ j ].godina_upisa == ISPIT [ j+1 ].godina_upisa)
                            {
                                a= ISPIT [ j ] ;
                                ISPIT [ j ] = ISPIT [ j+1 ] ;
                                ISPIT [ j+1 ] = a ;
                            }
                    }
            }

    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    printf("\n\n") ;
    printf("Posle sortiranja po prosecnoj oceni u opadajucem poretku \n\n");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; } printf("\n");
    printf("| %-15s | %-15s | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15s | %-15s | %-15s |\n", "Broj Indeksa", "Godina Upisa", "Ime", "Prezime", "Ocena I", "Ocena II", "Ocena III");
    for( k = 0 ; k < 137; k++) { printf("=") ; }
    printf("\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("| %-15d | %-15d | %-15.15s | %-25.25s | %-15.1f | %-15.1f | %-15.1f |\n",
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].broj_indeksa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].godina_upisa,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].ime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prezime_studenta,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_I,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_II ,
                                                      ISPIT [ i ].prosecna_ocena_III );

                                                        for( k = 0 ; k< 137; k++) { printf("_"); }
                                                        printf("\n");
        }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

I finally did it ! Nick S , your answer helped me a lot .
This is what a wanted to make .